# Unable `go get` a repository via an HTTP proxy

Tags: go, http-proxy

When I am trying to install Burrow https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow#build-and-install

```
go get github.com/linkedin/Burrow
```

I am getting the following error :

```
package gopkg.in/gcfg.v1: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/gcfg.v1" 
(https fetch: Get https://gopkg.in/gcfg.v1?go-get=1: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp :0: getsockopt: connection refused)
```

I have already set up proxy by:

```
export http_proxy=myproxy:port
export https_proxy=myproxy:port
```

**Edit:**

```
go get -u gopkg.in/gcfg.v1
```

also gives the same error:

```
package gopkg.in/gcfg.v1: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/gcfg.v1" 
(https fetch: Get https://gopkg.in/gcfg.v1?go-get=1: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp :0: getsockopt: connection refused)
```

**Edit1**:

```
go get -v gopkg.in/gcfg.v1

Fetching https://gopkg.in/gcfg.v1?go-get=1
https fetch failed: Get https://gopkg.in/gcfg.v1?go-get=1: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp :0: getsockopt: connection refused
package gopkg.in/gcfg.v1: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/gcfg.v1" (https fetch: Get https://gopkg.in/gcfg.v1?go-get=1: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp :0: getsockopt: connection refused)
```

Comment: That `:0` bit from the error message looks really strange. Any chance for us to see your *real* HTTP proxy specs (with hostname replaced with `example.com` or digits of IP address replaced by random values)?

Comment: my proxy is `export http_proxy=http.proxy.example.com:8080`. I am able to do a `wget https://gopkg.in/gcfg.v1` and getting a html.

Comment: Could you try running `go get -v gopkg.in/gcfg.v1` (notice the `-v` flag) and update your question?

Comment: @kostix updated

Comment: After setting `export http_proxy=proxy.domain.local:8080; export https_proxy=$http_proxy` and running `go get -v -u gopkg.in/gcfg.v1` I get: `http: error connecting to proxy http://proxy.domain.local:8080: dial tcp 192.168.2.20:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
gopkg.in/gcfg.v1 (download) ...` -- as you can see, it mentions both the proxy's name and a correct port (our proxy has been taken down recently so "unable to connect" is expected). I have `go1.7.4 linux/amd64`. I wonder what else could effect what you're observing.

Comment: I wonder why we get differently-formatted error messages. Though difference in Go versions could explain that.

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the same error. Turns out that my https proxy was incorrect. Make sure both http and https proxy are pointing to same proxy starting with http.

```
export http_proxy=<http://proxy:port>
export https_proxy=<http://proxy:port>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove env **HTTPS_PROXY** from your PC:

1. SystemProperty - Environment - current user variable/system variable : find and remove **HTTPS_PROXY**.
2. Restart your terminal to enable env modification to take effect.

Comment: How to remove through cli?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem using:

```
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
```

To a more long lasting solution the /etc/environment can be updated.